# Will cooking meat in a slow cooker longer than the recipe calls for have any adverse effects?

Tags: beef, cooking-time, slow-cooking

I have a recipe for slow cooker beef curry that calls for beef chunks, coconut milk, and red curry paste.  It says to cook on low for 8 or so hours.  Suppose that near the end of the 8 hours I suddenly have to go somewhere else for a few hours and can't take the food out of the slow cooker until I get back.

Will cooking the beef for 10, 12, or even 15+ hours degrade the quality of the finished dish?  I've heard that the longer you cook meat the better it is - is this actually true, and if so is there a limit?

Comment: @rumtscho Nothing older, but here's a recent one that's very similar: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/44911/25059

Comment: @logophobe thank you, that's what I was thinking of. Unless there is one even older, but I don't think so.